# ¿Como obtener json a partir de una consulta mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

## ¿Como obtener json a partir de una consulta mysql?

*Hola buen día, estoy aprendiendo json este código de abajo es un resultado en json, veo que la parte del objeto información no la obtiene de una consulta mysql, la parte de estudios esa si veo que la trae de mysql espero estar en lo correcto, lo que no se es como trabajarlo en php dejo el código de como lo estoy planteando que es el segundo código y si estoy en lo correcto irme por ese camino*

```
{
    "informacion": 
    {
    "id_paquete": "7",
    "paq_titulo": "titulo paquete",
    "estudios": 
    [
      {
       "est_titulo": "categoria",
       "especificaciones": "descripcion del producto"
      },
    ]
    }
```

Aqui es donde deseo trabajar para obtener el resultado de arriba PHP en json

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM paquetes_img");
$array_data=array();
while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
{
    $array_data[]=$data;
}
 $objeto=array
(
        "empleados"=>array
        (
            array("nombre"=>.$array_data[0]."edad"=>33),
            array("nombre"=>"maria","edad"=>30)

        ),
        "autos"=>array
        (
            array("marca"=>"ford","modelo"=>2016),
            array("marca"=>"Nissan","modelo"=>2015),
            array
            (
                "marca"=>array
                (
                    array("submarca"=>"sub0"),
                    array("submarca"=>"sub1"),
                    array("submarca"=>"sub2"),
                )
            )
        )
    );
echo json_encode($objeto,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta de forma que se pueda leer.

Comment: Ademas de lo que te pide juan, cual seria la pregunta?

Comment: Que tiene que ver el codigo que mostras con tu pregunta? y vuelvo a insistir, cual es la pregunta? de donde vienen los datos? cuales son las tablas? que query probaste que no te funciono?

Comment: Hola perdón, tenia problemas con la edición por eso no aparecía completa.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede conseguir con `json_encode` para pasar a JSON y `json_decode` para pasar de JSON a array.

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Esto devuelve:

> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

---

## Convertir Consulta MySQL en formato JSON

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo más copmpleto con una consulta a MySQL en este link: https://geekytheory.com/json-ii-creacion-de-un-json-a-partir-de-una-consulta-en-mysql

Te pongo la parte donde hace la consulta ([fuente del código](https://geekytheory.com/json-ii-creacion-de-un-json-a-partir-de-una-consulta-en-mysql)):

```
function getArraySQL($sql){
    //Creamos la conexión con la función anterior
    $conexion = connectDB();

    //generamos la consulta

        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); //si la conexión cancelar programa

    $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

    //guardamos en un array multidimensional todos los datos de la consulta
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    disconnectDB($conexion); //desconectamos la base de datos

    return $rawdata; //devolvemos el array
}

        $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
        echo json_encode($myArray);
```

---

Fuentes:

- http://docs.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php
- https://geekytheory.com/json-ii-creacion-de-un-json-a-partir-de-una-consulta-en-mysql